# Get string value from json starting from specific index

Tags: javascript, json

So I have this JSON:

```
{
 "posts":{
   "fields":{
     "date":"2015/01/24",
     "date_end":"2015/01/25",
     "time":"23:00 - 05:00"
   }
 }
}
```

How do i get into a variable the value from key *time* but only **05:00** characters if there are present, keeping in mind that *time* could have in some cases only **23:00** without **- 05:00**.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var time = data.fields.time[0].split(' - ');
time = time[1] || time[0] || '';
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/xojezi/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your example made me understand the logic. I forgot about split though...

Answer (score 0):

```
timeValues = fields['time'].split(' - ')
if (timeValues.length>1)
     return timeValues[1];
else
     return 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
xxx.time[0].split(" ")[xxx.time[0].split(" ").length - 1];
```